# Delete hash with specific key in array of hashes which has arbitrary value of links

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have this array of hashes

```
[{"No."=>1, "Shop ID"=>354, "Outlet Name"=>"St", "Outlet ID"=>511, "Outlet Icon"=>"https://m.sth.io/f5sdfsdfsf.png", "Registered Date"=>"08 June 2018 16:30", "Last Login"=>"15 minutes ago"},.....]
```

what I want to accomplish is to remove the outlet icon hash in the middle with most efficient way as possible.

I tried sth like this

```
data.reject! { |k| if k["Outlet Icon"]="" }
```

but couldn't get to a way of putting the link value to compare.

Thanks in advance to anyone willing to help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`arr.each {|h| h.delete("Outlet Icon")}`

It will remove the key "Outlet Icon" from every hash in the array.

Answer (score 1):

Input

```
a=[{"No."=>1, "Shop ID"=>354, "Outlet Name"=>"St", "Outlet ID"=>511, "Outlet Icon"=>"https://m.sth.io/f5sdfsdfsf.png", "Registered Date"=>"08 June 2018 16:30", "Last Login"=>"15 minutes ago"}]
```

Code

```
a.each do |h|
  h.delete_if{|k,v| k.strip.eql?"Outlet Icon"}
end
```

output

```
p a
[{"No."=>1, "Shop ID"=>354, "Outlet Name"=>"St", "Outlet ID"=>511, "Registered Date"=>"08 June 2018 16:30", "Last Login"=>"15 minutes ago"}]
```